# Who or what compiled /usr/share/dict/words?

Tags: history, dictionary

Wikipedia says it's part of the wishlist
Wordlist or Words package

> On Debian and Ubuntu, the words file is provided by the wordlist package, or its provider packages wbritish, wamerican, etc. On Fedora and Arch, the words file is provided by the words package.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix))

But from where is this compiled? I've been using it to 'help' solve  crosswords at work,  but there's a lot of words it is missing,  and a lot that I don't recognise.

What are the origins of this file?

Answer (score 6):

Over in BSDlandia you'll have to dig back through the 386bsd and possibly older sources:

http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/share/dict/?only_with_tag=MAIN

Looks like someone typed up words from "Webster's Second International" on account of the 1934 copyright elapsing according to this file:

http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/share/dict/README?rev=1.1&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&only_with_tag=MAIN

Answer (score 5):

If you follow the package descriptions to their source, that gives the information (many ultimate sources).  For [`wordlist`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/wbritish), that goes to [SCOWL (And Friends)](http://wordlist.aspell.net/), whose page lists other sources which are *compiled* into this collection.  Tracing the contributor for a given word is likely to be difficult though.

Further reading:

- [SCOWL (Spell Checker Oriented Word Lists) and Friends](http://wordlist.aspell.net/)

Answer (score -1):

I can't find a reference right now but I believe a lot of it comes from the [Moby Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby_Project) by [Grady Ward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grady_Ward)